# Error installing PyCrypto on Mac 10.9.5

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, python-3.4, pycrypto

i'm trying to install PyCrypto for Python 3.4 but i'm having problem with the C compiled programs.
it says that "error: cannot run C compiled program".
anyone have an idea how to fix it??

code:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/briansabbath/Desktop/pycrypto-2.6.1':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 456, in <module>
    core.setup(**kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 251, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 278, in run
    raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
RuntimeError: autoconf error
```

Comment: i tried to install via home-brew but thats another problem because i get an error while installing homebrew, and follow other suggestion that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 5):

This might indicate that you did not install C compiler likes gcc. Run the following command might help (command line tool must be installed in xcode):

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

The method that worked for me

```
brew install pip
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pycrypto
```

You can run it in a virtualenv. If you have a better way please leave a comment below!